# Integration Testing with Ruby and the assigns keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to perform some integration testing to see if the article gets updated. Here is my integration test:

```
test "update existing article" do 

    # create an article 
    @article = Article.new 
    @article.title = "title"
    @article.abstract = "abstract"
    @article.description = "description" 

    if @article.save 

      post "/articles/edit", :id => @article.id

      assert assigns(:article)

    end

  end
```

And here is my articles_controller implementation:

```
def edit

    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.xml { render :xml => @article }
    end

  end
```

The last line in test about assigns fails. From my understanding assigns(:article) means that the variable @article will be populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
post "/articles/edit", :id => @article.id
```

The problem is that the edit action takes a `GET`, not a `POST`, so it's probably never getting called. try:

```
get edit_article_path, :id => @article.id
```

(note that if you're running a controller test, it's best to use a symbol for the action name.)

Comment: by using get :edit I get the following error: 1) Error: 
test_update_existing_article(ArticleFlowsTest): 
ArgumentError: bad argument(expected URI object or URI string) 
/test/integration/adding_article_flows_test.rb:30:in `test_update_existing_article'

Comment: I am running integration test!

Comment: ah, sorry about that! Try using my update above, and subbing `edit_article_path` for `:edit`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. Hey where can I find all the helper path methods like the one you listed edit_article_path.

Comment: just run "rake routes" in the command line, in your project directory. Good luck!